# Listview Pagination - Index Out of range error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listview, pagination

I am having trouble implementing pagination onto a list of products held within a List View. Currently my pagination set up works fine if I do not call the ItemDataBound method but once I do, I repeatedly get the error that an Index was out of range when I try to navigate using my pagination.

This line seems to be causing the error, even though debug seems to show that it is finding the ID

```
int key = int.Parse(LV_Images.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Does anyone have a workaround this or can explain why this is happening??? Many thanks!

Comment: I can see that from the tags.  Is this *ASP.NET* though?  Windows Forms has a ListView control too, for example

Comment: if i am not wrong, the datakeys contain the key(s) of the record u are editing. meaning the primary key of a table( 1 or max 2 pk for a table)
On the other side, ur e.item.DataItemIndex is the index of the record in the control... u know the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only container you are using in this line is `DataKeys`. The possible cause of this is because `e.Item.DataItemIndex` is not in range. Can you please check what is the value of `DataItemIndex` when it throws this exception? Also, check whether the value exist for such index value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
int key = int.Parse(LV_Images.DataKeys[e.Item.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString());
```

I was having same error also, I was able to resolve it with this. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please expand on why `e.Item.DisplayIndex` should be used instead of `e.Item.DataItemIndex`.